# Is there a way to return the OS number format in R

Tags: r

I would like to make a function that exports text and, as a default, is able to determine the number format used by the operating system (e.g. "," or "." decimal separator). Are there any R functions that return this information?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Sys.localeconv()` which returns:

```
decimal_point     thousands_sep          grouping   int_curr_symbol   currency_symbol mon_decimal_point mon_thousands_sep 
          "."                ""                ""            "USD "               "$"               "."               "," 
 mon_grouping     positive_sign     negative_sign   int_frac_digits       frac_digits     p_cs_precedes    p_sep_by_space 
   "\003\003"                ""               "-"               "2"               "2"               "1"               "0" 
n_cs_precedes    n_sep_by_space       p_sign_posn       n_sign_posn 
          "1"               "0"               "1"               "1"
```